# Property does not exist on type

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am working on a project with Ionic2 and Angular2. When trying to run `ionic serve`, the data is retrieved without any errors. However, when trying to test on ios and running `ionic build ios`, I am getting the below compile time errors, that properties do not exist.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

I appreciate any suggestions.

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileService } from './profile.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    providers: [ProfileService]
})
export class HomePage {

    constructor(public d: HomeService){
        this.loadData();
    }

    loadData() {
     this.d.fbPromise.then( (FB) =>    this.data.getData(FB)).then(response => {
         this.data = response;
     });
   }
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

    <div class="profile-content" padding>
        <div class="content-header">
            <h2 class="name">{{ this.data.name }}</h2>


        <div class="interests-content">
            <h3>interests</h3>

            <span *ngFor="let interest of this.data.interests" >
                {{ interest.title }} : {{interest.name}}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Compile Time Errors:

```
[10:10:18]  Error: Error at /Users/zzz/Sites/angular-app/Flah/.tmp/pages/home/home.ngfactory.ts:330:47 
[10:10:18]  Property 'name' does not exist on type 'HomeService'. 
[10:10:18]  Error at /Users/zzz/Sites/angular-app/Flah/.tmp/pages/home/profhomeile.ngfactory.ts:349:72 
[10:10:18]  Error at /Users/zzz/Sites/angular-app/Flah/.tmp/pages/home/phomerofile.ngfactory.ts:354:72 
[10:10:18]  Property 'interests' does not exist on type 'HomeService'. 
[10:10:18]  ngc failed 
[10:10:18]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[10:10:18]  Error: Error
```

Comment: Where do you try to access `HomeService.name`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I added the template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `this` in view bindings

```
{{ this.data.name }}<
```

should be

```
{{ data.name }}<
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I made these changes and it is much cleaner now, however, I am still getting the same errors when trying to build for ios. Again, `ionic serve` works fine / no errors, `ionic build ios` generates the above described errors when trying to compile.

Comment: I guess `response` in `this.data.getData(FB)).then(response => {` is not what you expect.

Comment: If that were the case, how come `ionic serve` loads everything fine / without errors, utilizing the response object?

Comment: Especially, since I am statically setting the property fields in `home.service.ts`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Ionic but if `data.name` causes `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'HomeService'.` then it's obvious that `data` is an instance of `HomeService`.

Comment: Thank you sir, your suggestion helped point me in the right direction. As a hint to those experiencing the same issue, I recommend creating a property to hold the viewData for better separation from the service layer. Second, look in to the 'Elvis Operator' for data loaded asynchronously. Third, don't use `this.` in the view.

Answer (score 0):

change the name of the imported service file in dependency injection

import { ProfileService } from './profile.service';

constructor(public d:ProfileService ){}