# localstorage.setitem not working in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, local-storage

Here is my function below. I can see an object in the console.log with `res`:

```
login2(){
    console.log(this.user_form_value);
    console.log(this.password_form_value);
    this._loginService.login(this.user_form_value, this.password_form_value).subscribe(
      res => console.log(res.user),
      res2 =>localStorage.setItem("getLoggedInUserANG1",JSON.stringify(res2.user))
      )

  }
```

But when I try to store the same object in the local storage, it's not being saved. I'm new to angular but there isn't a bug and I don't know why it isn't not being saved.

After saving it I would also want to fetch the same one using `getitem` in an array variable and have it console.log.  I would like to understand the problem with the basics and where precisely I'm going wrong.

Below is the screenshot of my console.log

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `res.user` in `JSON.stringify(res2.user)`, since res2 is not defined till you set the localstorage

Comment: Were you able to get the data using `getItem` after setting it? I had the same issue once. The data in the local storage was not getting reflected instantly. After setting the data in the local storage, close the developer tools and reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res2` is not defined. I believe that you need take a look at [JavaScript Arrow Funcions docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Try it:

```
login2() {
    console.log(this.user_form_value);
    console.log(this.password_form_value);
    this._loginService.login(this.user_form_value, this.password_form_value).subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log(res.user);
            localStorage.setItem("getLoggedInUserANG1",JSON.stringify(res.user));
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: worked but where was i gone wrong ? and how do i get the same in a array variable and print it to console log , i am trying to fetch the username from the stored object like this but unable to `this.loggeduser_array  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("getLoggedInUserANG1"));
      console.log(this.loggeduser_array.username);` , please guide

Comment: `subscribe` receives a function as parameter. `res` is the param of your `subscribe`. When using arrow functions you can omit `{` and `}` if the function has only one statement. This IS NOT your cause. You do a `console.log` and after a `localStorage.setItem`. To solve it I added `{` and `}` to delimit the scope of the function. Can you plese explain a bit more about what do you mean with _"how do i get the same in a array variable and print it to console log"_? Or (best) crate a new question about it?

Comment: In the object that i am fetching, it has a parameter username, i want to fetch it, i am trying like this - `this.loggeduser_array  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("getLoggedInUserANG1"));
      console.log(this.loggeduser_array.username);` but unable to catch it, you can see this screenshot - https://www.dropbox.com/s/6odgf7mmlmdn93e/Screenshot%202017-05-24%2000.53.01.png?dl=0

Comment: Sorry, I really do not understand what are you trying... :( What is the output of `console.log(this.loggeduser_array.username);`? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: yes error Property 'username' does not exist on type 'any[]' , i want to fetch the username, please see the dropbox link image https://www.dropbox.com/s/6odgf7mmlmdn93e/Screenshot%202017-05-24%2000.53.01.png?dl=0

Comment: I believe this error (`Property 'username' does not exist on type 'any[]'`) is not ocurring in the line `console.log(this.loggeduser_array.username);`. See [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592029/property-does-not-exist-on-type).

Comment: its occuring on that line, see screenshot of my editor - https://www.dropbox.com/s/hyvjvqr8gzcl834/Screenshot%202017-05-24%2001.11.25.png?dl=0

Comment: this worked `console.log((this.loggeduser_array as any).name);` //angular is scary

Comment: This error seems to be related with TypeScript... Please, If this answer solved your problem consider [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it to informs others that your issue is resolved and to help future viewers of your question. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. It was because I was using chrome. I had to recreate my project and configure my default browser to edge and that's how it worked for me